# Verify iFrame content and update containing DIV Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a block of JQuery that was already provided by the previous developer but I am not 100% sure I understand what it is doing. I thought it had to do with setting the height of an iFrame based on its contents.

```
            var iframeId = "iframeFinancial"; 
            var origin = "http://content.net";

//I am not 100% sure what is going on over the next 3 lines    


                var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
                var eventListener = window[eventMethod];
                var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

            eventListener(messageEvent,function(e) {
                var message = e.data;
                if(e.origin !== origin) return;  // change to vanity url if applicable
                updateIFrame(message);
            },false);

            function updateIFrame(msg) {
                console.log('In Update Iframe Function');
                if(typeof msg != 'object') {
                    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId); // iframe id
                    iframe.setAttribute('height',msg);

                } else { // for multiple iframe support
                    var id = msg.id;
                    var height = msg.height;
                    var object = document.getElementById(id);
                    object.setAttribute('height',height);
                }
            }
```

But when the iFrame loads I never make it into the updateIFrame function based on what I am seeing in the console.

I also tried the following on my own but got this error:`Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`

```
document.getElementById("iframeFinancial").onload = function()
        {

      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('iframeFinancial');
      iFrameID.height = ""; 
      iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; 

      console.log('In new function');
        }
```

**I checked the page being loaded into the iFrame and found the following snippet of JS at the bottom of the page:**

```
  (function ($) {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'); // the container element of the phx content.
        var height = Math.max( wrapper.offsetHeight, wrapper.scrollHeight );
        parent.postMessage(height,"*");
    }(Phx.$));
```

Based on what is shown here do I need to update the JQUERY mentioned at the top of the question.

Comment: I suspect there is code in the page loaded by the iframe that is attempting to send a message up to the parent page using the "onmessage" or "message" event - the value of which should be the height of the frame.

Comment: @HamiltonLucas I updated my question with the JS from the page being loaded. Thanks for the info +1

Comment: Is the iframe hosted on the same domain as the parent? I am also curious if the line: "if(e.origin !== origin)" is what's causing the code to drop out before the updateIFrame method is called.

Comment: The three lines that you indicate that you're not sure about are attempting to attach an event listener to the message event. Those lines are trying to be clever and cross browser compliant by checking to see if the "window.addEventListener" method is defined, and then based upon that selecting the right method to use to attach an event listener. 

See this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Any idea why it is not working? lol.

Comment: I suspect that when (e.origin !== origin) is compared, they are not the same origin and as a result the updateIFrame method is not being called. See if you add a console.log() up into the event handler if you see that event handler being called (just above var message = e.data;)

Comment: @Denoteone to where is this iframe pointing to? The child page is on the same domain (and sub-domain) as the parent page? Is the child page on another site? If you have control of said child page, can you please post the relevant code of that as well? Or was that the only JS for the child page?

Comment: Actually @HamiltonLucas was correct the e.origin and origin where not matching up. When I corrected that my code worked as expected. If you want to create an answer for this Hamilton or whoever I will mark it answered.